# After building my own kernel I cannot load any module

Tags: kernel

**Story of my life**

I built my kernel according to: http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation.
I was able to boot my 3.14 kernel image. However when I want to insert rt2800usb I get the errors listed below.

*What went wrong?*

```
ERROR: could not insert 'rt2800usb': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

**This is dmesg**

```
[    3.994834] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    5.513101] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_results (err 0)
[    5.614248] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_assoc_resp (err 0)
[    5.694763] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_unexpected_4addr_frame (err 0)
[    5.781061] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_dfs_required (err 0)
[    5.870149] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err 0)
[    5.914206] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_stopped (err 0)
[    5.950349] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err 0)
[    5.977878] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cac_event (err 0)
[    5.994231] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_amsdu_to_8023s (err 0)
[    6.010568] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ref_bss (err 0)
[    6.026162] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_mandatory_rates (err 0)
[    6.042413] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_valid (err 0)
[    6.051279] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err 0)
[    6.058771] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_calculate_bitrate (err 0)
[    6.066982] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel (err 0)
[    6.074969] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_width_frame (err 0)
[    6.083480] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_classify8021d (err 0)
[    6.091159] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mlme_mgmt (err 0)
[    6.098824] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err 0)
[    6.105848] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_new (err 0)
[    6.112364] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err 0)
[    6.119430] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_notify (err 0)
[    6.127288] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_tx_mlme_mgmt (err 0)
[    6.134800] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_gtk_rekey_notify (err 0)
[    6.142658] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_bss_get_ie (err 0)
[    6.150053] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_assoc_timeout (err 0)
[    6.157558] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_spurious_frame (err 0)
[    6.165328] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined (err 0)
[    6.172559] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_compatible (err 0)
[    6.180442] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_obss_beacon (err 0)
[    6.188338] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err 0)
[    6.196274] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cqm_pktloss_notify (err 0)
[    6.204315] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_operating_class_to_band (err 0)
[    6.212799] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err 0)
[    6.219751] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_radiotap_iterator_init (err 0)
[    6.228048] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_notify_new_peer_candidate (err 0)
[    6.236574] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err 0)
[    6.243497] mac80211: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err 0)
[    6.251079] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_usable (err 0)
[    6.258626] mac80211: Unknown symbol rfc1042_header (err 0)
[    6.265416] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status (err 0)
[    6.272965] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_check_station_change (err 0)
[    6.281027] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_reg_can_beacon (err 0)
[    6.288569] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_ie (err 0)
[    6.295508] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unregister_wdev (err 0)
[    6.303221] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_del_sta (err 0)
[    6.310151] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_probe_status (err 0)
[    6.317489] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_data_to_8023 (err 0)
[    6.324915] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_radiotap_iterator_next (err 0)
[    6.333281] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_frequency (err 0)
[    6.341433] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt (err 0)
[    6.348425] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_hdrlen (err 0)
[    6.355378] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_create (err 0)
[    6.362921] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err 0)
[    6.370993] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_mesh_hdrlen (err 0)
[    6.378747] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_p2p_attr (err 0)
[    6.386144] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_frequency_to_channel (err 0)
[    6.394354] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_radar_event (err 0)
[    6.401656] mac80211: Unknown symbol bridge_tunnel_header (err 0)
[    6.408967] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_vendor_ie (err 0)
[    6.416498] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss (err 0)
[    6.423663] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err 0)
[    6.430053] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cqm_rssi_notify (err 0)
[    6.437698] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_auth_timeout (err 0)
[    6.445052] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_unprot_mlme_mgmt (err 0)
[    8.900938] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    9.353331] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   14.432017] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
[   14.462080] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[   17.240448] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   17.241175] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   18.837715] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor ondemand
[   18.837744] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor ondemand
[   18.914668] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
[   18.918494] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   23.782607] Adding 524284k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:5 across:2252796k SS
[   41.217212] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_results (err 0)
[   41.217388] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_assoc_resp (err 0)
[   41.217444] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_unexpected_4addr_frame (err 0)
[   41.217702] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_dfs_required (err 0)
[   41.217721] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err 0)
[   41.217796] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_stopped (err 0)
[   41.217977] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err 0)
[   41.217996] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cac_event (err 0)
[   41.218072] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_amsdu_to_8023s (err 0)
[   41.218147] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ref_bss (err 0)
[   41.218185] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_mandatory_rates (err 0)
[   41.218451] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_valid (err 0)
[   41.218468] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err 0)
[   41.218573] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_calculate_bitrate (err 0)
[   41.218686] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel (err 0)
[   41.218704] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_width_frame (err 0)
[   41.218747] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_classify8021d (err 0)
[   41.218764] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mlme_mgmt (err 0)
[   41.220579] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err 0)
[   41.220659] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_new (err 0)
[   41.220702] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err 0)
[   41.220721] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_notify (err 0)
[   41.220756] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_tx_mlme_mgmt (err 0)
[   41.220812] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_gtk_rekey_notify (err 0)
[   41.220887] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_bss_get_ie (err 0)
[   41.220956] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_assoc_timeout (err 0)
[   41.221001] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_spurious_frame (err 0)
[   41.221018] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined (err 0)
[   41.221036] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_compatible (err 0)
[   41.221087] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_obss_beacon (err 0)
[   41.221147] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err 0)
[   41.221165] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cqm_pktloss_notify (err 0)
[   41.221239] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_operating_class_to_band (err 0)
[   41.221318] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err 0)
[   41.221379] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_radiotap_iterator_init (err 0)
[   41.221397] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_notify_new_peer_candidate (err 0)
[   41.221474] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err 0)
[   41.221505] mac80211: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err 0)
[   41.221602] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_usable (err 0)
[   41.221641] mac80211: Unknown symbol rfc1042_header (err 0)
[   41.221719] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status (err 0)
[   41.221763] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_check_station_change (err 0)
[   41.221808] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_reg_can_beacon (err 0)
[   41.221834] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_ie (err 0)
[   41.221852] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unregister_wdev (err 0)
[   41.221867] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_del_sta (err 0)
[   41.221883] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_probe_status (err 0)
[   41.221901] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_data_to_8023 (err 0)
[   41.221918] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_radiotap_iterator_next (err 0)
[   41.222000] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_frequency (err 0)
[   41.222018] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt (err 0)
[   41.222124] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_hdrlen (err 0)
[   41.222177] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_create (err 0)
[   41.222203] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err 0)
[   41.222230] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_mesh_hdrlen (err 0)
[   41.222271] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_p2p_attr (err 0)
[   41.222298] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_frequency_to_channel (err 0)
[   41.222339] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_radar_event (err 0)
[   41.222359] mac80211: Unknown symbol bridge_tunnel_header (err 0)
[   41.230908] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_vendor_ie (err 0)
[   41.230944] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss (err 0)
[   41.230967] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err 0)
[   41.231015] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cqm_rssi_notify (err 0)
[   41.231077] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_auth_timeout (err 0)
[   41.231100] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_unprot_mlme_mgmt (err 0)
[  303.287756] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): error count: 1
[  303.287789] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): initial error at 1384107506: ext4_ext_map_blocks:3951: inode 101
[  303.287808] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): last error at 1384107506: ext4_ext_map_blocks:3951: inode 101
[  692.342374] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_results (err 0)
[  692.342480] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_assoc_resp (err 0)
[  692.342498] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_unexpected_4addr_frame (err 0)
[  692.342727] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_dfs_required (err 0)
[  692.342744] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err 0)
[  692.342811] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_stopped (err 0)
[  692.344657] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err 0)
[  692.344690] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cac_event (err 0)
[  692.344770] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_amsdu_to_8023s (err 0)
[  692.344844] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ref_bss (err 0)
[  692.344878] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_mandatory_rates (err 0)
[  692.345129] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_valid (err 0)
[  692.345144] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err 0)
[  692.345241] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_calculate_bitrate (err 0)
[  692.345346] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel (err 0)
[  692.345362] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_width_frame (err 0)
[  692.345402] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_classify8021d (err 0)
[  692.345418] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mlme_mgmt (err 0)
[  692.345451] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err 0)
[  692.345481] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_new (err 0)
[  692.345511] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err 0)
[  692.345525] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_notify (err 0)
[  692.345553] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_tx_mlme_mgmt (err 0)
[  692.345599] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_gtk_rekey_notify (err 0)
[  692.345664] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_bss_get_ie (err 0)
[  692.345725] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_assoc_timeout (err 0)
[  692.345768] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_spurious_frame (err 0)
[  692.345784] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined (err 0)
[  692.345798] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_compatible (err 0)
[  692.345847] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_obss_beacon (err 0)
[  692.345902] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err 0)
[  692.345917] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cqm_pktloss_notify (err 0)
[  692.345982] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_operating_class_to_band (err 0)
[  692.346053] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err 0)
[  692.346106] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_radiotap_iterator_init (err 0)
[  692.346122] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_notify_new_peer_candidate (err 0)
[  692.346190] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err 0)
[  692.346216] mac80211: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err 0)
[  692.346283] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_usable (err 0)
[  692.346315] mac80211: Unknown symbol rfc1042_header (err 0)
[  692.346382] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status (err 0)
[  692.346412] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_check_station_change (err 0)
[  692.346447] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_reg_can_beacon (err 0)
[  692.346468] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_ie (err 0)
[  692.346485] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unregister_wdev (err 0)
[  692.346498] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_del_sta (err 0)
[  692.346512] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_probe_status (err 0)
[  692.346528] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_data_to_8023 (err 0)
[  692.346543] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_radiotap_iterator_next (err 0)
[  692.346606] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_frequency (err 0)
[  692.346621] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt (err 0)
[  692.346715] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_hdrlen (err 0)
[  692.346753] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_create (err 0)
[  692.346774] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err 0)
[  692.346797] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_mesh_hdrlen (err 0)
[  692.346836] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_p2p_attr (err 0)
[  692.346859] mac80211: Unknown symbol ieee80211_frequency_to_channel (err 0)
[  692.346896] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_radar_event (err 0)
[  692.352279] mac80211: Unknown symbol bridge_tunnel_header (err 0)
[  692.352361] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_vendor_ie (err 0)
[  692.352379] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss (err 0)
[  692.352399] mac80211: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err 0)
[  692.352441] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cqm_rssi_notify (err 0)
[  692.352496] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_auth_timeout (err 0)
[  692.352518] mac80211: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_unprot_mlme_mgmt (err 0)
```

**What I did:**

*Le preparation:*

- I copied the config from kernel 3.13 from the Pi to my laptop
- make oldconfig (and pressed always enter)
- Changed the source code of one driver (just changed two numbers which control a timeout)

*On my laptop I cross compiled the kernel*

- make CROSS_COMPILE=~/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi- ARCH=arm
- make CROSS_COMPILE=~/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi- ARCH=arm modules

*Installed into a temp dir:*

- mkdir /tmp/rasp-mod
- make CROSS_COMPILE=~/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi- ARCH=arm INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/tmp/rasp-mod modules_install

*Copied all the shit to to Pi*

- scp -rp /tmp/rasp-mod/lib arch/arm/boot/Image pi@raspberry:~/

*On the Pi installed the image*

- cp -rp Image /boot/kernel.img

*Installed the modules into the library path:*

- cp -rp lib /

Everything should work, because the kernel is booting and the modules are found.
Everything I want is to use this damn module. Compiling worked, modules are found and I have no clue what's the problem and why modprobe is complaining ):

```
uname -a == /lib/modules/kernel*
```

Comment: Have you recompiled the modules with the new kernel source that you used to build the kernel ?

Comment: Made some edits which explained how I built and installed the kernel. I compiled everything completely and built _all_ modules from the sources.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe "scp -rp /tmp/rasp-mod/lib arch/arm/boot/Image pi@raspberry:~/" resulted in corrupted file transfer. Is there a way to check whether all files are still working?